# How to limit current precisely?

Tags: current, current-limiting, circuit-protection

I would like a way to limit the current of a circuit to exactly 100mA (+/- 2-5%).  This is on a relatively high voltage circuit (100V to ground), and the current is normally pulsed with pretty fast rise times (let's say 1-2 microseconds) using another circuit (low-side) as a switch and pulse shaper.  What I need is a way to limit the current in case the other circuit malfunctions (fails short-circuit, in the worst case).  I would like to limit it within also a few microseconds (ie: not more than a few microseconds of overcurrent).  I would like this part of the circuit to not use much power when it is not actively limiting the current.  In case of overcurrent, the current can either be clamped it at 100mA or possibly disconnected until things reset, but clamp would be ok.  What is the best type of circuit to use in this case?

(Background: this is on a very compact board, there are less a few tens of mm^2 to fit this in).

(The average power available is limited to less than 0.3W at the source, even in a short circuit, so power dissipation is not as big of an issue as it might seem; the source will drop pretty quick from 100V to around 3V if there is sustained 100mA, but that takes milliseconds not microseconds)

Comment: Can the circuit be ground-referred, or does it have to be high-side referred? How little power must it draw? Do you have a voltage reference in your circuit? Or perhaps a regulated low-voltage supply?

Comment: 100mA and 100V means 10W maximum power dissipation. Can you dissipate that kind of power?

Comment: I am also concerned with how much power you're going to have to dissipate. 10 W is no joke. You're going to need a serious heatsink. Then again, it may only be dissipating that much power for an few microseconds.

Comment: Detector is no problem (only a matter of engineering :-) ). Memory says that the long ago classic fast switch for clamping was a 2N3866 -  a TP66 RF transistor. Now I'll look it up:- .... Yes!. But only 30V alas. Should not be hard with a FET. [2N3866](http://www.centralsemi.com/PDFs/products/2N3866_SERIES.PDF) - blast from the past.

Comment: By putting a current sensor on the low side and driving either a low side or hgighh side switch (bipolar or MOSFET you need only low V in the sense cct. Or if you MUST ground the load you can float the sense cct off the HV rail. Size is harder.

Comment: I looked at TI's [protection circuitry page](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/power-management/hot-swap-control-protection-monitoring-overview.page?DCMP=hpa_pmp_hotswap&HQS=protectioncircuitry) and clicked on "hot swap controllers". I found a [positive voltage hot swap controller](http://www.ti.com/product/lm5069/description) with an absolute max rating of 100V. You can pick the sense resistor Rs to limit your current to 100 mA. The formula for the sense resistor is Rs = 55 mV / Ilim where Ilim is your 100 mA. I don't know if this part satisfies your timing and area specs but I would look around.

Comment: @ZekeR:  I do have low-side current sensing, and a regulated low voltage supply, but due to pretty stringent reliability requirements this needs to still limit current if any of those modules fail.  So I would ideally like a self-contained high-side current limiter which is also powered from the high side.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: Any tips for how to sense current off the HV rail? I do have low side current sensor, this is the circuit that is supposed to catch the case where that fails... so high-side-only is preferred.  Thank you for your comments above, feel free to post an answer :)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: The source is limited to ~0.3W internally.  It can supply ~3mA at 100V continuous, and drops to about 3V at 100mA after a few milliseconds of high current, so the continuous power dissipation is not too bad.

Comment: @AlexI - I hoped to get back to this in more detail but time is not going to allow. You can use a current mirror on the high side to "reflect' the current to the low side and use a low side switch. BUT easiest is probably an 'upside down' cct on the high side rail powered by a resistor derived supply from ground (say 10 volts below rail) with a rail to rail in & out comparator driving a high side switch. Looks almost exactly like how it would look on the low side but FET is referred to comparator V+ rather than V-. Probably minimal components. Ref. Comp. FET few Rs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a high-side constant current circuit using a PNP transistor and op-amp: -

[image]

It needs to be modified a little to take one hundred volts though: -

1. Op-amp needs a top rail of V+ (as shown) and a lower power rail maybe at V+ - 10 volts
2. PNP transistor needs to be rated for at least 150 volts
3. Vref needs to be positive rail referenced by using a precision voltage reference such as a shunt reference - it should replace R1.

How it works - lets say Vref is 1 volt below V+. Due to op-amp negative feedback Vref is forced to be across R2. With a voltage of 1V across R2 and a resistance of 10 ohms for R2 it implies that current taken by the load is limited to 100mA.

Having said all of this, the volt drop of R2 (1V) may be too much and a smaller value of Vref adopted. It could be reduced to 100mV and R2 dropped to 1 ohm without much difficulty. An op-amp with output rail-to rail capability is needed as well as the op-amp being able to sense its inputs at the positive rail too. It also needs to be fast and possibly avoid saturation when the load taken is under 100mA - this could be done with extra circuitry.

Anyway, that's the general approach I would consider.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something like this (with 15V power supplies)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTrLzf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(Changed error in schematic.)

But I'd have to think about how to change it for 100V.. (Reduce R1?)
And I'm don't think it will turn on very fast.
(Gate capacitance times R1.)

Comment: You want to move the PFET M1 *downstream* of Q1, since the way it is now, when \$V_{OUT}\$ drops, the PFET will turn ON again (without limiting current). Additionally, OP is asking for an accurate current limit. While you might be able to tweak this for exactly 100mA on your bench, that will be subject to production variation and *lots* of variation over temperature.

Comment: @ZekeR, Hmm I didn't think it mattered which came first.  Are you talking about Vout dropping because Q1 turns on?  Re accuracy:   He says +/- 2-5%, that would be doable for a few.. but not for production.. as you say.

Comment: Yes, when Q1 turns on it'll connect the PFET's gate to its drain. This is otherwise known as a "diode-connected" device. A diode-connected transistor has no ability to regulate current.

Comment: @ZekeR, Oh snap!  you are right.. my bad, I'll edit my picture.  Thanks.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold: Thanks!  This could do the job.  I think you're relying on a certain (predictable) voltage across R1 to bias Q1 though?  Unfortunately my 100V is not fixed, it can be anywhere 30-100V normally or down to 3-4V if the output is shorted for a while.

Comment: @AlexI, the circuit depends on the pnp turning on with ~0.6V across R3... for precise you'd have to tweak R3.  The input voltage divider has to have enough voltage to turn on the pFet... but other than that it should work down to 5V or so.  it depends on the pfet.